# Create nav-tabs with directives?

Tags: angularjs

I have a nav-tabs in my view

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-controller="myController">   
           <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/Page1')}"><a href="#/Page2">myPage1</a></li>          
           <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/Page2')}"><a href="#/Page2">myPage2</a> </li> 
        </ul>
```

How can I write it into a directive? The problem is the braces..

Comment: your problem explanation is severely lacking in details

Comment: Have you tried http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and its tab directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry that I first now corresponds to the question. I have found a solution to the problem.

My directives:

```
myApp.directive('userNavbar', function(){

return {
    restrict : 'AE',
    templateUrl : '../js/partials/userNavbarTemplates.html',
    controller : function($scope, $element, $location) {
        $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {

            var active = false;

            if (viewLocation === $location.path()) {
                active = true;
            }
            return active;
        };
    }
};
```

});

And my userNavbarTemplates:

```
    <title>userNavbar</title>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/page1')}">
                <a href="#/Page1">nav. to page1</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/page2')}">
                <a href="#/Page2">nav. to page2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And in my View can I add

```
<div data-user-Navbar></div>
```